# JQuery update the value after 1 click?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to update the following span

```
<span class="help-block">Your card will automatically reload $<span id="autoAmount">0</span> when your balance is lower than your reload threshold.</span>
```

with the value taken from code below,

```
<div class="controls">
    <div class="btn-group radioButtons amountButtons" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                @if (Model.PresetValues.Count > 0){
                     foreach (int value in Model.PresetValues) {
                        <button type="button" data-value="@value" class="btn amtButtons @(Model.chargeViewModel.ChargeAmount == value ? "active" : "")">$@value</button>
                     } 
                }                   
                <button type="button" data-value="other" class="btn toggleDiv toggleOnce amtButtons" data-toggle-id="#manualAmount">Other</button>
            </div>               
            <input type="hidden" class="radioHidden validate required validateAmount" value="" id="amount" name="ChargeAmount">

</div>
```

After I click the 'yes' button from this

```
<li class="control-group">
        <label for="autoReload" class="control-label">Auto Reload</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="btn-group radioButtons radioToggleCollapse" data-toggle-id="#autoReloadExtra" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                <button type="button" data-value="no" class="btn active">No</button>
                <button type="button" data-value="yes" class="btn">Yes</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" class="radioHidden" value="@(Model.IsAutoReload ? "True" : "False")" id="autoReload" name="IsAutoReload">
        </div>
    </li>
```

I have the following script,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST"
    }).success(function() {
       var callAjax = $('.amtButtons').click(function () {
           $("#autoAmount").html($('#amount').val());
      });
   });       
</script>
```

This works relatively well, however I am encountering two issues.

1) I have to click the value twice for it to update

2) If I click 'other' twice, it shows $other, whereas I'd like it to display whatever is in the 'manualAmounts' value when it is clicked.

I tried making a fiddle... but don't really know how to use it properly. This at least can show a general layout of what I'm trying to do though

http://jsfiddle.net/vfJtG/

EDIT:

Everything works except for the span displaying $other if I click it twice still, does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: Please create a js-fiddle and remove the c#/asp.net-mvc tags since they are not relevant.

Comment: @Screenmutt sorry I don't know what you mean by a fiddle.

Comment: [jsFiddle.net](https://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @screenmutt sorry that doesnt work but i just googled it and found it, thanks I'll post an updated ver. soon

Comment: I'm guessing the value in `#amount` is being updated on a postback or ajax call.  If so, jQuery is not seeing the new value to update the span with until the next time the button is clicked, which might explain why it takes 2 clicks.

Comment: The problem with your `other` button seems to just be that it uses different logic to determine the amount than the other buttons, so you need to update your click handle appropriately.

Comment: @TomPietrosanti sorry I dont understand what you mean by the problem iwth the other button, I have fixed the value in amount to load, however it still stores the value of other if i click it twice..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and the delay in responding.  I meant that your logic generically takes the `value` from whichever button was clicked, including the 'other' button.  You would need to write the logic to get the value from the `manualAmount` field and run that when the "other" button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnysooter/vfJtG/4/) and here's the Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Cache the selections
    var autoReloadCheck = $(".autoReloaded"),
        autoAmmount = $("#autoAmount"),
        ammount = $('#amount');

    //Replaced your two buttons with a simple checkbox
    autoReloadCheck.on('click', function(){
        if(!autoReloadCheck.is(':checked'))
            autoAmmount.html("0");
    });

    $('.amtButtons').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this); //Capture which button was clicked

        if($this.data("toggle-id") === "#manualAmount"){
             $this.data("value", $("#manualAmountInput").val()); //If the "other" was clicked, set the value according to what is in the input box
        }

        if(autoReloadCheck.is(':checked')){ //Is autoReload checked?
            autoAmmount.html($this.data("value"));
        }
    });
});
```

**Update based on comment**

New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnysooter/vfJtG/13/)

```
var autoReloadCheck = $(".autoReloaded"),
    autoAmmount = $("#autoAmount"),
    ammount = $('#amount'),
    plusMinus = $(".plusminus"),
    otherValue = $('*[data-toggle-id="#manualAmount"]');

function updateOthervalue(newValue){
    otherValue.data("value", newValue);
    plusMinus.data("value", newValue);
    plusMinus.val(plusMinus.data("value"));
    updateReloadSpan(newValue);
}

function updateReloadSpan(newAmount){
    if(autoReloadCheck.is(':checked')){
        ammount.val(newAmount);
        autoAmmount.html(newAmount);
    }
}

autoReloadCheck.on('click', function(){
    if(!autoReloadCheck.is(':checked'))
        autoAmmount.html("0");
});

$(".minus").on('click', function() {
    if(plusMinus.data("value") >= 15){
        var newValue = otherValue.data("value") - plusMinus.data("increment");
        updateOthervalue(newValue);
    }
});

$(".plus").on('click', function() {
    if(plusMinus.data("value") < plusMinus.data("max")){
        var newValue = otherValue.data("value") + plusMinus.data("increment");
        updateOthervalue(newValue);
    }
});

$('.amtButtons').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.data("toggle-id") === "#manualAmount"){
        $this.data("value", plusMinus.data("value"));
    }
    updateReloadSpan($this.data("value"));
});
```

Comment: Hi Jonny, I've tried to modify the code slightly and I have two problems. Previously, I had the code

"@* $.ajax({
           type: "POST"
       }).success(function() { "

so that it would change automatically, however this is not the case when i am clicking the +/- buttons. In addition, when merging this with my code the hidden field for other appears and goes away almost instantly after. Any ideas?

Comment: I've put in a new fiddle. But as for the hidden field code, I can't help you with what I can't see.